# Is it possible to color blocks of source text in TeXmaker?

Tags: texmaker

This is a question about the software itself, not how to code something in latex.

I am currently in the process of editing, which for me involves copying and pasting large blocks of text around, modifying paragraphs, and creating new ones. I am finding it hard to keep track of what I consider "finished" for now, what I'm in the process of editing, and what I have copy pasted to aid my writing.

I'm wondering if a plugin exists for texmaker which allows me to color blocks of source text in different colors, to help me keep track of what is what.

Comment: Mmm well you can edit and customize the colors of the editor in `Options>Configure TeXmaker>Editor` but the parts and colors you can edit are limited. TeXStudio (a fork of TeXmaker have a wider range of options for its editor). But in both cases I think you won't find what you need. 

IMO I preffer for the tasks you mentioned another editor called `Sublime Text 2` improved with a package called `LaTeX Tools`. I love the Monokai bright color scheme, and using multiple cursors you can edit faster the text.

Comment: You can fold the edited part selecting the lines ready or using inside the code `% (fold) ... % (end)` when you create inside Sublime Text chapters, sectiosn, subsections, etc. I don't know if you enjoy this option.